# find or aggregate by date

Tags: mongodb

I have a date in my document. How do I query for all documents that are no more than 7 days old. I cannot assume that the time on the requestor machine and the database are in sync.

Comment: Tip: If you want a duration of 7 generic 24-hour days, just ask for days. `Instant.now().minus( Duration.ofDays( 7 ) )`

Comment: Above was just an example. What I really want is, to do date calculation on DB side

Comment: All your times should be in UTC so that timezone doesn't figure into it.

Comment: Close vote seems invalid, as requirements are clear

Comment: And someone roll backed :D

Answer (score 0):

You can get the server datetime using "serverStatus" command:

In mongo shell:

```
server_time = db.adminCommand("serverStatus")['localTime'].getTime();
db.mycollection.find( { "change_date": { $gt: new Date((server_time) - 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)  }} )
```

In Java:

```
MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient();
MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase("dbname");
Document serverStatus = database.runCommand(new Document("serverStatus", 1));
Instant server_time = (Instant) serverStatus.get("localTime");
```

Comment: But this means doing it in two parts. First get the time and then send it in find, which might be out of sync. How to do it as part of one query.